# eBPF : How to get syscall id using raw_tracepoint/sys_exit

Tags: linux, ebpf, libbpf

I’d like to use raw_tracepoint with libbpf to record syscalls .
Is there any way to get syscall_id using  bpf raw tracepoint program  SEC("raw_tracepoint/sys_exit") ?
I tried to search the documents about raw tracepoints and tracepoints, but I didn’t find any answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use btf raw tracepoint, with the syscall number saved in the 'orig_ax' register. You can use BPF_CORE_READ(regs, orig_ax) to read it.

```
SEC("tp_btf/sys_exit")
__s32 BPF_PROG(xm_btf_rtp__sys_exit, struct pt_regs *regs, __s64 ret) {
    pid_t pid = __xm_get_pid();
    __u32 tid = __xm_get_tid();
    __u64 delay_ns = 0;


    __s64 syscall_nr = BPF_CORE_READ(regs, orig_ax);
```